# Subsonic 3 ActiveRecords Update Dirty Columns are always empty

Tags: subsonic3

Any idea why this is happening? The issue was posted here:
[N Tiers with SubSonic 3, Dirty Columns collection is alwayes empty on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138102/n-tiers-with-subsonic-3-dirty-columns-collection-is-alwayes-empty-on-update/1139976#1139976)

Comment: Please don't repost the same question.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is to execute the q.SetIsLoaded(true) before updating any column. That way the dirty column collection gets updated when modifying. I hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks Luis. This was a show-stopper for me so I moved on to using EF instead since I did not get an answer.